# How do I get just a specific directory in a TFS repo via the command line

Tags: tfs

I have a powershell build script. The powershell build scripts clones several TFS hosted git repositories.I have a large (non git) TFS repo that contains a folder that I need to access the contents of in the powershell build script.

How can I have the build script get just the folder I'm interested in without having to get the whole TFS source tree, using the command line.

I have tried using `tf.exe get [pathspec]` which complained that I had no workspace. So I created one, but once created the `get` then it just says `All files are up to date.` but the directory does not contain any files at all...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to map source to the workspace fist. `All files are up to date` means the files in that folder are already the latest version. You can try to delete the files from the folder first, then re-run the command, this time you will get the files again.

- Navigate to an exsiting workspace (Already mapped), or create a new
  workspace then map source to local folder (click `No` if `workspace modified` dialog popped up, if click `Yes` it will get the latest source files automately, then when you run the `tf get` command you will get the messgae `All files are up to date` again.)
- Run the `tf get` command under the workspace path.

eg: Created a workspace named: `1031`

```
cd E:\user\WorkSpace\1031
tf get $/LCScrum/2/W1/Views /recursive
```

Refer to [Get command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command) for more information.

[image]

Comment: I get the all files up to date even though the folder is actually completely empty (except for the `$tf` folder). We've decided to move the files we need into a git repo though to make things simpler

Comment: @SamHolder Seems you didn't map the workspace correctly. Just try to re-map the worspace to a new local folder or create a new workspace as mentioned in above answer. Then try it again. Of course git repo is also an option.